# SyntaxError con un String con comillas

Tags: javascript

quisiera saber como escribir las comillas en este código para que el navegador no me bote un error de Syntaxis. Gracias.

```js
var codigo='<img src="+origen1.Attribute('src')+">'
```

Comment: me da el mismo error de syntaxis

Comment: var codigo='<img src=\"' + origen1.Attribute('src') + '\">'

Comment: var codigo='<img src='+ origen1.Attribute('src') +'>'

Comment: <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false --> <!-- language: lang-js --> var codigo="<img src='" + origen1.Attribute("src") + "'>"; <!-- end snippet -->

Comment: la probe pero con una modificacion:    var codigo='<img src=\" +origen1.Attribute("src")+ \">';

Comment: Hay varias combinaciones posibles que te pueden ser útiles y equivalentes.